# TradingView Pine Script strategy multiple time frames

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

I am trying to apply Bollinger bands in Tradingnview using Pine script. I have calculated all the variables (simple moving average, upper and lower bounds) and used close/open price using a 1-day frame, however, I want to implement a strategy that relies on this time frame, but executes the order on a lower resolution, e.g. 1-hour time frame. Basically, I receive a trigger using 1-day information and want to execute the order as soon as possible. Did anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 8):

For handling multi timeframe you can use the `security()` function.

Let's say you want a buy signal on the 1h 7-RSI crossing above 30 on a day where 7-day MA is above 21-days MA.

Set your chart timeframe to 1h (current timeframe) and use this for your script:

```
//@version=4

// Higher Time Frame
htf_fast_sma = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", sma(close, 7), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
htf_slow_sma = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", sma(close, 21), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Higher TF: Fast SMA above Slow SMA
high_tf_buy_signal = htf_fast_sma > htf_slow_sma

// Current TF: 7-RSI crossing over 30
curr_tf_buy_signal = crossover(rsi(close, 7), 30)

buy_signal = high_tf_buy_signal and curr_tf_buy_signal
plotshape(buy_signal ? low : na, 'Buy',  shape.labelup, location.belowbar)
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped! Security() is the way to go. One thing I found is that one can put strategy(... process_orders_on_close=true) to execute orders immediately.

Comment: Can someone by any chance also answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232821/tradingview-strategy-entry-on-close-price